# Response is not defined for a mongoose function findOneAndUpdate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am updating and returning(new Object) a existing object in the database with mongoose **findOneAndUpdate** but getting an error

**Error**

```
response is not defined
    at Function.module.exports.updateProfile ........
```

**In router File**

```
router.post('/edit_profile', (req, res) => {
let updateProfile = new Profile({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    username: req.body.username,
    gender: req.body.gender,
    bio: req.body.bio,
    user_id: req.body.user_id
});


console.log(updateProfile);           //consoling data Place(1)


Profile.updateProfile(updateProfile.user_id, (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
        console.log("Update User");
        console.log(user);
        res.json({
            user: user
        })
    }
})
})
```

**consoled data at Place(1)**

```
{ _id: 5c9cd517b3b7db248c6d7981,
  name: 'Shivva',
  email: 'ritinbhardwaj933@gmail.com',
  username: 'zzz',
  gender: 'Male',
  bio: 'I am HOwdy Member',
  user_id: '5c9cd47bf3d9bb1ea8cbfcbe' }
```

**In profile.js**

```
module.exports.updateProfile = (id, callback) => {
let query = { user_id: id };
console.log(query);                //consoling data Place(2)

    Profile.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $set: response }, { new: true }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
        callback(null, user);
    }
    });
}
```

**consoled data at Place(2)**

```
{ user_id: '5c9cd47bf3d9bb1ea8cbfcbe' }
```

**Error**

The error i am getting is response is not defined a the Function.module.exports.updateProfile

**Error**

the accepted solution worked but now it is returning the error

```
collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely, in this line you have used variable response but never have you initialised it.

```
Profile.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $set: response }, { new: true }, (err, user) => {
```

That response word should be replaced with an object with whatever changes you want eg.`{ name: 'jason bourne' }`

And honestly you don't need to create an instance like what you have done below because you aren't using that anywhere.

```
let updateProfile = new Profile({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    username: req.body.username,
    gender: req.body.gender,
    bio: req.body.bio,
    user_id: req.body.user_id
});
```

Comment: The thing is the word response is used in your code which is not defined elsewhere

Comment: collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead

Comment: @ShivaChandel It is not an error. Just a warning. The code is outdated as

Comment: @ShivaChandel It's safer to use the non-deprecated methods because if you update the package to later ones, those functions might not even be in the package.